# Global variable resetting in loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

I am attempting to do a problem from [advent of code](http://adventofcode.com/day/3), and I can't seem to crack it. It is supposed to collect a set of unique coordinates, then output their count. My main variable, `coords_list` is instantiated outside of a for loop, then added to inside that `for`.

For some reason, though, every time I append to it within the `for`, it appears to 'reset,' so at max my return list is a list of `coords_list`'s initial value, plus the most recent value I appended to it.

It's quite possible I'm just missing something simple. Still, any help would be awesome.

### Output

```
coords_list: [[0, 0]]
START -- coords: [0, 0], vector: (1, 0), instruction: >
END -- coords: [1, 0], coords_list: [[0, 0], [1, 0]]
input: >, len: 2
------
coords_list: [[0, 0]]
START -- coords: [0, 0], vector: (0, 1), instruction: ^
END -- coords: [0, 1], coords_list: [[0, 0], [0, 1]]
START -- coords: [0, 1], vector: (1, 0), instruction: >
END -- coords: [1, 1], coords_list: [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
START -- coords: [1, 1], vector: (0, -1), instruction: v
END -- coords: [1, 0], coords_list: [[0, 0], [1, 0]]
START -- coords: [1, 0], vector: (-1, 0), instruction: <
END -- coords: [0, 0], coords_list: [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
input: ^>v<, len: 2
------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 47, in <module>
AssertionError
```

### Code

```
def return_vector(chary):

    if chary == "^":
        ret_value = (0,1)
    elif chary == "v":
        ret_value = (0,-1)
    elif chary == ">":
        ret_value = (1, 0)
    elif chary == "<":
        ret_value = (-1, 0)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Expecting one of '^','v','>','<', got {}".format(chary))

    return ret_value

def main(input):
    coords_list = [[0,0]]
    coords = [0,0]
    lst_input = list(input)
    debug_iterator, debug_loop = 0, 10
    print("coords_list: {}".format(coords_list))

    for instruction in lst_input:
        vector = return_vector(instruction)


        if debug_iterator < debug_loop:
            print("START -- coords: {}, vector: {}, instruction: {}".format(coords, vector, instruction))

        coords[0] += vector[0]
        coords[1] += vector[1]

        if coords not in coords_list:
            coords_list.append(coords)

        if debug_iterator < debug_loop:
            print("END -- coords: {}, coords_list: {}".format(coords, coords_list))
            debug_iterator += 1

    print('input: {}, len: {}\n------'.format(input, len(coords_list)))
    return(len(coords))

assert main('>') == 2
assert main('^>v<') == 4
assert main('^v^v^v^v^v') == 2

print("main(INPUT) == {}".format(main(INPUT)))


assert return_vector('^') == (0,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `coords_list.append(coords)`, you are appending a reference to the one `coords` object, which you then change. Instead, you want a copy. You could do so with `coords[:]`, but using an immutable [tuple](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) or [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) would be much more appropriate here. How about

```
def main(inp):
    coords = set()
    cur = (0, 0)
    coords.add(cur)
    for instruction in inp:
        vector = return_vector(instruction)
        cur = (cur[0] + vector[0], cur[1] + vector[1])
        coords.add(cur)
    return len(coords)
```

Note a couple of other changes:

- `coords_list` is really much more of a set. Renamed to `coords` and made a set. This simplifies adding and makes the membership tests faster for large sets of coordinates.
- Renamed `input`, since [that is a built-in](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#input)
- `list(input)` iterates over the input already. You then iterate over the list. Instead, it's faster and easier to just iterate once over the input.
- Remove debugging code
- <strike>Use two variables for the current position.</strike> Use a tuple for the current position.

Comment: Ya, I thought about using a tuple for the list of coordinates. Then I didn't. I guess that would have helped. Thanks!